# pywinauto: Click button on warning window

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

There's a script controls program on Windows. The program throws a warning window with two buttons and I need to click on one of them. After that, the window could appear again up to 5 times. Here's the function that does it.

```
def yes_max_iteration_window(cls) -> None:
    sleep(5) # wait for first warning
    for _ in range(5): # can reappear up to 5 times
        if cls.dlg().child_window(class_name="#32770").exists():
            cls.dlg().child_window(class_name="#32770").child_window(
                title="Да", class_name="Button"
            ).click()
            sleep(2)
```

`cls.dlg()` is the func that returns the main program window.

When I run this single func while the warning exists, it does well and close it several times - I can say the identifiers of the elements are correct. But when I run the whole script from the beginning it cannot do anything.

What is wrong with that code and how can I click the button?

I use `v.0.6.8`

I tried to replace the func with one that just says if it can see the elements and start the script - it said that elements exist.
There are other functions that deal with other warning windows and they can click buttons
I tried print_control_identifiers on the warning window but on it, the script detects the error and restarts.

Comment: It seems like you're saying that this function works exactly like you want it to, but your script doesn't. However, your question doesn't include the script, so I don't know how anyone can offer advice on how to fix it. I mean, if your script really doesn't "do anything", maybe you're not actually calling the function.

Comment: this looks like it is part of a class, but where is the rest of the code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To reproduce the example you'd need to have the program to control, which is complicated to install, and a modeling schemes which are NDA covered. Class has run() method which gets the algorithm of modeling conststs steps (which are func names) and kwargs for it. The function is called - debagger stops there when it doesn't include click() event.